# Undergraduate Physics Journals

Tags: soft-question, education

I'm currently an undergraduate physics student and I've recently completed a research project with one of my professors this past half-year or so. I'm interested in submitting what I have right now to an appropriate research journal. Does anyone have a journal in mind that is more-so tailored to undergrads? My work was on muon spin spectroscopy, FYI.

Comment: Many colleges will have a forum for presenting undergraduate research. The one at my place is rather grandly called the *'Research Symposium'* (which is not in keeping with [the Ph.D. Comics naming advice](http://phdcomics.com/comics.php?f=1704), but there you have it).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is about what journal to publish in and not physics. This might be appropriate for [chat].

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/107201/2451

Comment: What has your professor suggested?  They are the experts in the field, and will know if a suitable journal exists.

Comment: I agree with @CDCM--your advisor knows best. In my opinion, I would suggest not to target some undergrad-oriented journal. If the project is original, interesting, and advanced enough, maybe you could try and submit it to a big journal like Physical Review B. Maybe some grad students or former undergrad researchers in your group would know of an appropriate journal for your work.